# How can we set UITexfiled in a single Horizontal line for Universal App applying Auto Layout Programmatically with Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

**ViewController.swift**

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate
{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(textField_Name)
    view.addSubview(textField_Address)
    view.addSubview(textField_City)
    view.addSubview(textField_State)
    view.addSubview(textField_Zip)
    view.addSubview(textField_Country)
    view.addSubview(textField_Email)
    view.addSubview(label_chargeCreditCard)
    view.addSubview(textField_CreditcardNumber)
    view.addSubview(textField_ExpirationDate)
    view.addSubview(textField_Signature)


    //--------------- constraints

    //make dictionary for views
    let viewsDictionary = [
        "view1_Name":textField_Name,
        "view2_Address":textField_Address,
        "view3_City":textField_City,
        "view4_State":textField_State,
        "view5_Zip":textField_Zip,
        "view6_Country":textField_Country,
        "view7_Email":textField_Email,
        "view8_ChargeCreditCard":label_chargeCreditCard,
        "view9_CreditCardNumber":textField_CreditcardNumber,
        "view10_ExpirationDate":textField_ExpirationDate,
        "view11_Signature":textField_Signature]


    let metricsDictionary = [
        "view1_Name_Height": 30.0,
        "view1_Name_Width":420.0,
        "view2_Address_Height":30.0,
        "view2_Address_Width":420.0,
        "view3_City_Height":30.0,
        "view3_City_Width":150.0,
        "view4_State_Height":30.0,
        "view4_State_Width":150.0,
        "view5_Zip_Height":30.0,
        "view5_Zip_Width":120.0,
        "view6_Country_Height":30.0,
        "view6_Country_Width":420.0,
        "view7_Email_Height":30.0,
        "view7_Email_Width":420.0,
        "view8_ChargeCreditCard_Height":30.0,
        "view8_ChargeCreditCard_Width":100.0,
        "view9_CreditCardNumber_Height":30.0,
        "view9_CreditCardNumber_Width":420.0,
        "view10_ExpirationDate_Height":30.0,
        "view10_ExpirationDate_Width":150.0,
        "view11_Signature_Height":30.0,
        "view11_Signature_Width":150.0]


    //sizing constraints

    //view1
    let view11_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view1_Name(view1_Name_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    let view11_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:[view1_Name(view1_Name_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_Name.addConstraints(view11_constraint_H)
    textField_Name.addConstraints(view11_constraint_V)

    //view2
    let view22_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view2_Address(view2_Address_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    let view22_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:[view2_Address(view2_Address_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_Address.addConstraints(view22_constraint_H)
    textField_Address.addConstraints(view22_constraint_V)

    // view3
    let view33_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view3_City(view3_City_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    let view33_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view3_City(view3_City_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_City.addConstraints(view33_constraint_H)
    textField_City.addConstraints(view33_constraint_V)

    // view4
    let view44_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view4_State(view4_State_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)


    let view44_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view4_State(view4_State_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_State.addConstraints(view44_constraint_H)
    textField_State.addConstraints(view44_constraint_V)

    // view5
    let view55_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view5_Zip(view5_Zip_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)


    let view55_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view5_Zip(view5_Zip_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_Zip.addConstraints(view55_constraint_H)
    textField_Zip.addConstraints(view55_constraint_V)

    // view6
    let view66_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view6_Country(view6_Country_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)


    let view66_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view6_Country(view6_Country_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_Country.addConstraints(view66_constraint_H)
    textField_Country.addConstraints(view66_constraint_V)

    // view7
    let view77_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view7_Email(view7_Email_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    let view77_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view7_Email(view7_Email_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_Email.addConstraints(view77_constraint_H)
    textField_Email.addConstraints(view77_constraint_V)


    // view8
    let view88_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view8_ChargeCreditCard(view8_ChargeCreditCard_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    let view88_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view8_ChargeCreditCard(view8_ChargeCreditCard_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    label_chargeCreditCard.addConstraints(view88_constraint_H)
    label_chargeCreditCard.addConstraints(view88_constraint_V)

    // view9
    let view99_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view9_CreditCardNumber(view9_CreditCardNumber_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)


    let view99_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view9_CreditCardNumber(view9_CreditCardNumber_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_CreditcardNumber.addConstraints(view99_constraint_H)
    textField_CreditcardNumber.addConstraints(view99_constraint_V)

    // view10
    let view1000_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view10_ExpirationDate(view10_ExpirationDate_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    let view1000_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view10_ExpirationDate(view10_ExpirationDate_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_ExpirationDate.addConstraints(view1000_constraint_H)
    textField_ExpirationDate.addConstraints(view1000_constraint_V)


    // view11
    let view1001_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view11_Signature(view11_Signature_Width)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    let view1001_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:[view11_Signature(view11_Signature_Height)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: metricsDictionary,
        views: viewsDictionary)

    textField_Signature.addConstraints(view1001_constraint_H)
    textField_Signature.addConstraints(view1001_constraint_V)

    /****** position constraints ******/

    //views
    let view111_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[view1_Name]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view222_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[view2_Address]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view333_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[view3_City(==view4_State)]-10-[view4_State(==view5_Zip)]-10-[view5_Zip]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view444_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-20-[view1_Name]-5-[view2_Address]-5-[view4_State]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view555_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-20-[view1_Name]-5-[view2_Address]-5-[view5_Zip]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view666_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[view6_Country]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view777_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[view7_Email]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view888_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[view8_ChargeCreditCard]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view999_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[view9_CreditCardNumber]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view10001_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[view10_ExpirationDate(==view11_Signature)]-5-[view11_Signature]-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-20-[view1_Name]-5-[view2_Address]-5-[view3_City]-5-[view6_Country]-5-[view7_Email]-5-[view8_ChargeCreditCard]-5-[view9_CreditCardNumber]-5-[view10_ExpirationDate]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading,
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view_constraint_V1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-20-[view1_Name]-5-[view2_Address]-5-[view3_City]-5-[view6_Country]-5-[view7_Email]-5-[view8_ChargeCreditCard]-5-[view9_CreditCardNumber]-5-[view11_Signature]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading,
        metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    view.addConstraints(view111_constraint_H)
    view.addConstraints(view222_constraint_H)
    view.addConstraints(view333_constraint_H)
    view.addConstraints(view444_constraint_V)
    view.addConstraints(view555_constraint_V)
    view.addConstraints(view666_constraint_H)
    view.addConstraints(view777_constraint_H)
    view.addConstraints(view888_constraint_H)
    view.addConstraints(view999_constraint_H)
    view.addConstraints(view10001_constraint_H)
    view.addConstraints(view_constraint_V)
    view.addConstraints(view_constraint_V1)

}

lazy var textField_Name: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "Name : "
    return view
}()

lazy var textField_Address: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "Address : "
    return view
}()


lazy var textField_City: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "City : "
    return view
}()

lazy var textField_State: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "State : "
    return view
}()

lazy var textField_Zip: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "Zip : "
    return view
}()

lazy var textField_Country: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "Country : "
    return view
}()

lazy var textField_Email: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "Email : "
    return view
}()

lazy var label_chargeCreditCard: UILabel! = {
    let view = UILabel()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.text = "Please charge my credit card : "
    return view
}()

lazy var textField_CreditcardNumber: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "Credit Card# : "
    return view
}()

lazy var textField_ExpirationDate: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "Expiration Date: "
    return view
}()

lazy var textField_Signature: UITextField! = {
    let view = UITextField()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    view.placeholder = "Signature : "
    return view
}()
}
```

Here I have tried to set Last UITextField In a single horizontal line that is, First ExpirationDate: and then Signature: but Expiration date is hidden behind the UITextField of Signature as per image in Current Output of this program shown , I think may b below mentioned line have to modify to solve my this issue but i am not sure any changes can be applied.

"let view10001_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|-[view10_ExpirationDate(==view11_Signature)]-5-[view11_Signature]-|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0),
            metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)"

**Getting output above code:**

[image]

Desired Output That i need like This Below FormDemo image[image: FromDemo Image]

Will anybody Please Guide me to fix this issue ?